# BreezeJs/EntityFramework Order By null/empty string handling

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have an application making use of BreezeJs querying a standard WebApi controller backed by an EntityFramework and SQL store. When I use an order by clause, I wish NULL and empty string values to always be sorted last (for BOTH ascending and descending order).

In SQL or even EF server side this is not a difficult task. However, I've not been able to locate the documentation for BreezeJs which shows how this can be accomplished.

The ideal solution would be some way to modify my EF context so this is the default behavior when any Order By is detected, prior to query hitting the DB. Failing that, perhaps there's a way I've missed  in Breeze itself to specify how nulls are handled in the results.

Worst case, I'll need to write two separate queries client side and merge the results, one for with and one without values in the specified column.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

Breeze currently has a class called **LocalQueryComparisonOptions** that may be used to control whether client side ordering is case sensitive and whether string comparisons should be SQL92 compliant. The idea here is that this class should be used to match whatever ordering rules are used by whatever server implementation you have selected.

It sounds like what you want is to also have the option to **completely** control local ordering of a query, probably by providing your own ordering function.  If this is the case, please add this to the breeze [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) and vote for it.  This seems very reasonable and if it gets enough votes I think it makes sense to add it to the product.

Note that you will still need to insure that EF ( or whatever backend you are using) adheres to these same ordering rules.

Also, out of curiosity, how do you make EF always order nulls this way?

Comment: When querying on the server side, one can simply do something like this:

db.MyCollection.OrderBy(n=>n.MyPotentiallyNullField == null).ThenBy(n=>n.MyPotentiallyNullField);

This is because "false" will be ordered before the actual field itself. I wish there was a way to make this ordering occur on the SERVER before the client even gets the results. If I was to do that on the client, Chrome would be very angry at the multi million rows it gets ;)

Comment: You can force this ordering to occur on the server by returning your IQueryable with the clauses you mention above included. Of course, any order by clauses coming  coming from the client will be applied after these, but if there is no client side order by clause on the same properties then you will get the results that you want.  Does this make sense?

Comment: It does, but I'd rather not have the overhead in cases where there's no sort requested, rather than querying off another end point. I would rather have that be transparent. I'm currently exploring intercepting queries at the db context level and dynamically adding my clause when an orderby is detected on a nullable string field. Failing that, I'll most likely do that which you suggest, simply make a new end point on my Api controller that already has the sort "built-in".

Comment: You know you have access to the Request within your Web API Action method (e.g, `this.Request.RequestUri.Query`) and can look for the "$orderby" OData keyword. If you see it, you know a sort is requested and can add your magic LINQ phrases ... if not, you carry on without them. It's hacky ... but not TOO hacky :)